# Is there any way to read all missed push notifications on app's launch

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

If my app has been closed for a while but some push notification were coming for the app and the user was not following them, is there a way to read all of those notification on the app's next opening?

Comment: No, you can't. Only in Notification Center you can find pushes list, cuz it has private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No, There is nothing which will provide you all the missed notifications , you can only get information about notification which was tapped to open the app.

Answer (score 0):

No way to get information about the missed notifications, only way to see it in notification center.